# Pattern matching in bash with tuple-like arguments

Tags: bash

I want to pass a variable number of 'tuples' as arguments into a bash script and go through them in a loop using pattern matching, something like this:

```
for *,* in "$@"; do
    #do something with first part of tuple
    #do something with second part of tuple
done
```

is this possible? If so, how do I access each part of the tuple?

For example I would like to call my script like:

`bash bashscript.sh first_file.xls,1 second_file,2 third_file,2 ... nth_file,1`

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and there is more than one way to do it. You can use the prefix/suffix expansion syntax on variables (e.g. `${var#prefix}`, `${var##prefix}`, `${var%suffix}`, `${var%%suffix}` - these remove either the shortest or longest prefix/suffix matching the specified pattern). Or you can replace the positional parameters with e.g. `IFS=, set -- ${var}` (although you'd have to make sure to save the rest of the original parameters in some way first so you can continue your loop). You can use arrays, if your version of `bash` is new enough (and if it isn't it's pretty old...). Those are probably three of the better methods, but there are others...

Edit: some examples using the suffix/prefix expansions:

```
for tuple in first_file.xls,1
do
  echo ${tuple%,*}     # "first_file.xls"
  echo ${tuple#*,}     # "1"
done
```

If your tuples are more than 2-ary, that method's a little more complex; for example:

```
for tuple in x,y,z
do
  first=${tuple%%,*}
  rest=${tuple#${first}}
  second=${rest%%,*}
  last=${rest#*,}
done
```

In that case you might prefer @chepner's answer of `IFS=, read first second third <<< "${tuple}"`... Otherwise, the bookkeeping can get hairy for large tuples. Setting an array from the tuple would be an acceptable alternative as well.

For simple pairs, though, I tend to prefer just stripping off a prefix/suffix as appropriate...

Comment: could you give a more concrete example of how I would use prefix and suffix given the arguments I gave in my example?

Answer (score 5):

Since `bash` doesn't have a tuple datatype (it just has strings), you need would need to encode and decode them yourself. For example:

```
$ bash bashscript.sh first_file.xls,1 second_file,2 third_file,2 ... nth_file,1
```

In `bashscript.sh`:

```
for tuple in "$@"; do
    IFS=, read first second <<< "$tuple"
    ...
 done
```